# Add prefix value to input filed in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have requirement like this.

```
<label>Website Address</label>
                    <span><input type="text" class="form-factor" data-ng-model="websiteUrl"/></span>
```

I have the HTML code like this. Once the user enter text in website URL field I need to add prefix to the URL with `http://`.

If the user is entering the URL with `http://`. then no need add the `http://` prefix.

How can i do with in AngularJS .

Please suggest

Comment: should the model contain the http:// or just your output?

Comment: Try using or creating a filter that handles all the regex checks and returns the url as you wish

Comment: whenever you are getting your output text you can easily append know ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there is also another possibility to use a formater and parser to complete the task at the model level. I put the code in here from another solution, since the code there is hosted external:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19482887/3641016

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.input1 = "";
    $scope.input2 = "";
  })
  .filter('prefixHttp', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return input.indexOf("http://") == 0 ? input : 'http://' + input;
    };
  })
  .directive('httpPrefix', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        function ensureHttpPrefix(value) {
          // Need to add prefix if we don't have http:// prefix already AND we don't have part of it
          if (value && !/^(https?):\/\//i.test(value) && 'http://'.indexOf(value) !== 0 && 'https://'.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
            controller.$setViewValue('http://' + value);
            controller.$render();
            return 'http://' + value;
          } else
            return value;
        }
        controller.$formatters.push(ensureHttpPrefix);
        controller.$parsers.splice(0, 0, ensureHttpPrefix);
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <label>prefix the output
    <input ng-model="input1" />{{input1 | prefixHttp}}
  </label>
  <br/>

  <label>prefix the model
    <input ng-model="input2" http-prefix/>{{input2}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.In my case I need to add **http://**  to the input filed when the user start to type on input filed. is it possible??

Comment: @Kichu ther is this possibility. have a look at the improved answer